# SPLIT at whitespace followed by Character

Tags: google-sheets

I need to perform a SPLIT at either a `(` or `[` but my problem is if the characters have a leading whitespace that also needs to removed from the split results. This is what I currently have (extracted from a longer function):

`SPLIT(UPPER(TO_TEXT({D$3:D$50;L$3:L$50})),"([",true)`

Is there someway to define the split with optional whitespace? I tried to use REGEXEXTRACT but it didn't work.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to wrap it in `TRIM` :-)